# Undo a function in Wordpress that is not (seemingly) hooked to an action?

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I need to change this function in `wp-includes\comment-template.php`

```
function get_comments_link($post_id = 0) {
    return apply_filters( 'get_comments_link', get_permalink( $post_id ) . '#comments', $post_id );
}
```

to this

```
function get_comments_link($post_id = 0) {
    return apply_filters( 'get_comments_link', get_permalink( $post_id ) . '#disqusthread', $post_id );
}
```

But since it isn't connected to an "action hook" I don't know how to "undo" or "overwrite" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's a *filter* hook. Whenever you find `do_action()` or `apply_filters()` in the core code, then you'll have the chance to modify the behavior or execute custom code.

Action hooks allow us to run something at the `do_action` point, they don't return anything. Filter hooks allow us to modify the output or the parameters being used at the `apply_filters()` point, and we must return something in our callback function.
See [Actions and filters are not the same thing](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/).

Hooks follow the convention `add_HOOK( 'hook-name', 'callback_function', PRIORITY, NUM_PARAMETERS );`.

In the OP case, it should be used like (in functions.php):

```
add_filter( 'get_comments_link', 'callback_so_18783534', 10, 2 );

function callback_so_18783534( $link, $post_id ) {
    return get_permalink( $post_id ) . '#disqusthread';
}
```

Upon testing, I see that posts that don't have comments, don't get this filter applied (through `comments_link()`). [It is hardcoded](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L990) and there's no hook available. Looks like the only solution for this is jQuery.

Comment: I don't get it. When I look at the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) it states that the first part is the `$tag`, which is `The action hook to which the function to be removed is hooked.` Maybe I would understand it better if you could take the code you posted apart and explained evey part of it (especially the `add_filter` line).

Comment: Also, I just tested your code and it only works for the first post in the loop, so I'm guessing it is *not* added to the loop?

Comment: I wrote the code in the tablet. I'll have to test and debug when I'm on the desktop.

Comment: Posts that don't have comments don't pass through this filter. Looks like there's no solution for this but jQuery.

Comment: That's a bummer. I'll mark yours as an answer though. Thanks for the effort!